# How do I get ssh-agent to work in all terminals?

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

I have set up automatic (password less) ssh login to some servers using ssh-copy-id. `ssh-agent` works only from the terminal where it was run. How do I get `ssh-add` to work in all my terminals?

Naturally, I would not prefer SSH key without a passphrase.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

If you're logging into a graphical session, arrange to start `ssh-agent` during your session startup. Some distributions already do that for you. If yours doesn't, arrange to run `ssh-agent` from your session startup script or from your window manager. How you do that depends on your desktop environment and your window manager. For example, if you start your window manager manually, simply replace the call to `my_favorite_wm` by `ssh-agent my_favorite_wm`.

Do not start `ssh-agent` from `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`, since these files are executed by each new interactive shell. The place to start `ssh-agent` is in a session startup file such as `.profile` or `.xsession`.

If you want to use the same SSH agent on all processes no matter where you logged in from, you can make it always use the same socket name, instead of using a randomly-named socket. For example, you might put this in your `~/.profile`:

```
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=~/.ssh/ssh-agent.$HOSTNAME.sock
ssh-add -l 2>/dev/null >/dev/null
if [ $? -ge 2 ]; then
  ssh-agent -a "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" >/dev/null
fi
```

Comment: FYI, the reason it checks for `$? -ge 2` is because exit code 1 is when the ssh-agent has no keys, but ssh-agent is already running.

Comment: Note that some desktop environments (e.g. Ubuntu Mate) may automatically run ssh-agent for you but you have to run `ssh-add` without parameters to add private keys into your keyring. For example, when you first connect to remote machine that contains private keys, you have to run `ssh-add` on the remote matchine to get the keys into your client machine keyring.

Comment: I am curious, when it's possible to set this up in a few lines of a shell script, what is the purpose of `keychain`, `ssh-ident` or other projects.

Comment: FYI, if you have a .bashrc file, you have to put theses lines instead of `.profile` (see `head ~/.profile` for explanations)

Comment: @Asenar No. `.profile` is the right file for what runs at login time. `.bashrc` runs every time you open a terminal. See https://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile

Answer (score 12):

You probably want a program such as [Keychain](http://www.funtoo.org/Keychain), which was designed for this exact purpose. From the man page:

```
DESCRIPTION
   keychain is a manager for ssh-agent, typically run from ~/.bash_profile.
   It allows your shells and cron jobs to share a single ssh-agent process.
```

Comment: really like this one!

Comment: Great! thank you. Works perfectly.

Comment: this works great, after downloading the compressed file from Github, make sure you add the complete path of uncompressed keychain-2.8.5 directory to your ~/.bash_profile export PATH=$PATH: line

Comment: What is the advantage of `keychain` over the the accepted answer?

Comment: @PavelŠimerda Interestingly, I found this question when trying to figure out how to accomplish this *without* `keychain`, as I've been using it for (literally) decades now.  I'm answering another Super User question and wanted to provide the basic `ssh-agent` instructions.  That said, I think `keychain` is great for (at least) several reasons, at least for my workflow preferences. (1) It's a single command that consolidates `ssh-agent` and `ssh-add` into a one-liner and "just works". (2) One-liners keep my profile "cleaner". (3) It outputs `fish` shell syntax (my preferred shell).

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds, `keychain` also supports `gpg`, which is also great

Comment: @JellyFilledNuts Great point, but you'll probably want to tag Pavel for notification since that's who was asking what the advantages are ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Apply it to your desktop environment or window manager.  When I've done this manually in the past with a custom `~/.Xclients`, I just used this as the last line:

```
ssh-agent mywindowmanger
```

There might be some DE's that have their own setup options for this, although it appears to me that (e.g.) KDE does not.  Currently, it seems that mine was run via code from `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc-common` (presumably something done by fedora), since it is active for all users regardless of DE/WM and the parent process command is `$HOME/.Xclients`, but that file does not reference `ssh-agent` (whereas `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc-common` does).

If you don't have a `~/.Xclients`, you could create one with just that one line, but you will need to know the command that starts your DE/WM.